# Multiple select on enum column laravel 8

Tags: database, laravel, enums, laravel-8, multi-select

I have an enum column in my migration

```php
$table->enum('service_dmo', ['DCO', 'SEP', 'SEM'])->nullable();
```

I want to use a multiple select in a form in my blade view, am trying this but it didn't work:

```html
<select class="form-control @if($errors->has('service_dmo')) is-invalid @endif"
    name="service_dmo" multiple="">

    <option></option>
    @foreach($courrier->service_dmo AS dmo)    
        <option value="{{ $dmo  }}">{{ $dmo  }}</option>
    @endforeach

</select>
```

Comment: Do you have any error ? Also, when you do `@foreach($courrier->service_dmo AS dmo)` see that you are not writing `$` before `dmo`, I hope it is a typo here.

Comment: Please eloborate what is not working

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstood the usage of `enum` inside your migrations. enum column inside a table means the column can just have these three values you mentioned. so the code you shared is not going to print these three values for you, it is going to print all the `rows` you have inserted in this table and their `service_dmo` value